# compare <pagenumber/> with <totalpages/> in freemarker

Tags: html, netsuite, freemarker

I want to compare the `<pagenumber/>` with the value of `<totalpages/>`  in Netsuite - Advanced PDF Template / Freemarker, but unable to compare the values of `pagenumber` and `totalpages`.
I tried:

```
<#assign pgno> <pagenumber/> </#assign>
<#assign totpg> <totalpages/> </#assign>
<#if pgno == totpg>
<td>This is true condition</td>  
<#else>
<td>This is False condition</td>   
</#if>
```

I tried to compare both `pagenumber` and `totalpages` but unable to compare both. I want to compare `pagenumber` with `totalpages`. Only else condition is getting executed here though IF statement is true. Please Help to solve the issue!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot compare `<pagenumber/>` and `<totalpages/>` in Freemarker.  They are XML tags which are used by the BFO PDF generation engine, which NetSuite passes the output of Freemarker to.

Comment: Thanks! I want to add some text/data (e.g. This is Computer Generated Bill) exact on last page of Advance PDF template in Netsuite; where content of page ends .  Problem is as number of pages change, data/text  occur on all pages or change its position. Unable to fix this issue.